# Large vendor.js in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm running ng build --prod, and i'm getting a vendor module size of 1.42MB (which is after AOT compiling, default for the cli w/ --prod flag, and uglify, also default for --prod flag)

Not sure what the issue is here. I want to learn more about what goes into that vendor module, and if I'm using AOT compiling, why's it so large?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use some additional dependencies?

Comment: Nothing besides the angular router/forms modules

Answer (score 4):

In order to view the content of your bundle you can use [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer)

All you have to do is run  `source-map-explorer vendor.bundle.js`

Comment: How cool, never knew about this. This helped me find out that it wasn't AOT compiling, so i've specified this now (even though I thought it should have been?) So now, I've removed the compiler and we're at 1.42 MB. When I enable the --prod flag and minify, it still sits at 1.42 MB, but all the other files seem to minify fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Which part is minifying and which isn't?